# Can't add TaxService to QBO with .NET SDK

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

How do I create a tax rate in QBO using API v3 and the TaxService resource? When I try to add it the same way as I would any other object, Visual Studio gives me this error: "The type 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method Intuit.Ipp.DataService.DataService.Add(T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService' to 'Intuit.Ipp.Data.IEntity'."

Here's the code:

```
Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService ts = new Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService();
// Populate fields here...
DataService ds = new DataService(ServiceContext);
Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService newTs = ds.Add<Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService>(ts);
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of .net devkit which got released on Dec'15. TaxService support is added only in this version. Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/intuit_.net_sdk_release_notes

Comment: Yes. I have another method which successfully adds a tax agency, which was added in the Dec. '14 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GlobalTaxService endpoint and JSON format only. Try this code:

```
GlobalTaxService taxSvc = new GlobalTaxService(context);
            Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService taxCodetobeAdded = new Data.TaxService();
            taxCodetobeAdded.TaxCode = "taxC_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

            QueryService<TaxAgency> taxagency = new QueryService<TaxAgency>(context);
            TaxAgency taxagencyResult = taxagency.ExecuteIdsQuery("select * from TaxAgency").FirstOrDefault<TaxAgency>();                          



            List<TaxRateDetails> lstTaxRate = new List<TaxRateDetails>();
            TaxRateDetails taxdetail1 = new TaxRateDetails();
            taxdetail1.TaxRateName = "taxR1_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            taxdetail1.RateValue = 3m;
            taxdetail1.RateValueSpecified = true;
            taxdetail1.TaxAgencyId = taxagencyResult.Id.ToString();
            taxdetail1.TaxApplicableOn = TaxRateApplicableOnEnum.Sales;
            taxdetail1.TaxApplicableOnSpecified = true;
            lstTaxRate.Add(taxdetail1);

            TaxRateDetails taxdetail2 = new TaxRateDetails();
            taxdetail2.TaxRateName = "taxR2_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            taxdetail2.RateValue = 2m;
            taxdetail2.RateValueSpecified = true;
            taxdetail2.TaxAgencyId = taxagencyResult.Id.ToString();
            taxdetail2.TaxApplicableOn = TaxRateApplicableOnEnum.Sales;
            taxdetail2.TaxApplicableOnSpecified = true;
            lstTaxRate.Add(taxdetail2);

            //TaxRateDetails taxdetail3 = new TaxRateDetails();
            //taxdetail3.TaxRateName = "rate298";
            //taxdetail3.TaxRateId = "2";

            //lstTaxRate.Add(taxdetail3);

            taxCodetobeAdded.TaxRateDetails = lstTaxRate.ToArray();

            Intuit.Ipp.Data.TaxService taxCodeAdded = taxSvc.AddTaxCode(taxCodetobeAdded);
```

Comment: Thanks. But now I get a 500 error with "Ids service endpoint was not found". I'm using the same service context for GlobalTaxService as for QueryService, just as in your code. What else could be causing that error?

Comment: Update to the latest version of SDK and enable request/response logs to get details of the error in the response logs.

Comment: Check the override configuration docs for enabling .Net SDK request/response logs.

Comment: Request:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TaxService xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <TaxCode>Seattle Sales Tax</TaxCode>
  <TaxRateDetails>
    <TaxRateName>Seattle Sales Tax</TaxRateName>
    <RateValue>2.75</RateValue>
    <TaxAgencyId>2</TaxAgencyId>
    <TaxApplicableOn>Sales</TaxApplicableOn>
  </TaxRateDetails>
</TaxService>

Comment: Response:
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"An application error has occurred while processing your request","Detail":"System Failure Error: Cannot consume content type","code":"10000"}],"type":"SystemFault"},"time":"2015-02-03T21:35:39.676-08:00"}

Comment: I believe TaxService endpoint supports JSON only. Can you try to use JSON format?  Use this after serviceContext obj is created-                 context.IppConfiguration.Message.Request.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;
                context.IppConfiguration.Message.Response.SerializationFormat = Intuit.Ipp.Core.Configuration.SerializationFormat.Json;

Comment: Your req looks malformed to me. I tried to format it in Notepad++ and got errors. If you still face issues, add you code in your question.

Comment: The JSON fixed it, thanks! I'm surprised that the SDK would send XML if the service only supports JSON, but at least now we know.

Comment: SDK has both settings, depending on which one the user wants to use. Glad this worked.

Comment: Hi @nimishashrivastava,
                                          I am using the above code and added serialization format of json. But when the addtaxcode function execute then I got an error like "
"error when creating tax service w/o GlobalServiceTax
This operation cannot be performed after the request has been submitted"

Please help me about this issue. 

Thanks in Advance.